# Attempted import error: 'Detail' is not exported from './components/pages/List'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, components

I dont really see what I am doing wrong here.

I want to be able to show my header and my list and my detail on the App.js.
but the:

```
:import { Header }  from  './components/pages/Header';
import { List }  from  './components/pages/Detail';
import { Detail }  from  './components/pages/List';
```

does not seem to work for me.

here's the whole code from App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import { Header }  from  './components/pages/Header';
import { List }  from  './components/pages/Detail';
import { Detail }  from  './components/pages/List';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  return (

    <Router>
    <div className="App">
<Header/>
<Switch>
<Route path="/" exact component={widthRouter(List)} />
<Route path="/Detail/:id" component={widthRouter(Detail)} />
</Switch>


    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here's from Header.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import logo from '../logo.svg';

export class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
            <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
             React-Demo
            </p>
           
          </header>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Header;
```

here's from List.js:

```
import React, { component}  from 'react';

export class list extends Component {
render() {
    return (

        <div>

            List!
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default List
```

here's from Detail.js:

```
import React, { component}  from 'react';

export class Detail extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
    
            <div>
    
                Detail!
            </div>
        )
    }
    }
    
export default Detail
```

Anybody that knows what I am doing wrong?

Help is much appreciated! :)

---

So I have done the things you have said in the comments. ( I think )

But it is not working for me still. This is the error I am getting now from the terminal:

```
*"

*Failed to compile.
src\components\pages\Detail.js
  Line 3:29:  'Component' is not defined  no-undef     
src\components\pages\List.js
  Line 3:27:  'Component' is not defined  no-undef     
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.* 
"*
```

so this is my code for now.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Header  from  './components/pages/Header';
import Detail  from  './components/pages/Detail';
import List from  './components/pages/List';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (

    <Router>
    <div className="App">
<Header/>
<Switch>
<Route path="/" exact component={withRouter(List)} />
<Route path="/Detail/:id" component={withRouter(Detail)} />
</Switch>

    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Header.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import logo from './logo.svg';

export class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
            <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
             React-Demo
            </p>
           
          </header>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

export default Header;
List.js :

```
import React, { component}  from 'react';

export class List extends Component {
render() {
    return (

        <div>

            List!
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default List;
```

Detail.js :

```
import React, { component}  from 'react';

export class Detail extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
    
            <div>
    
                Detail!
            </div>
        )
    }
    }
    
export default Detail;
```

Comment: The question is different after your edit. Actually you have the answer in your error log. JS syntax is case-sensitive. You must change `component` to `Component` where you import it from React.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me!!!!! :) Thank u so much ! As for the question, it might help someone going through the same issue seeing how I did? or should the last part be deleted u mean?

Answer (score 2):

You are importing `Detail` component in a wrong way.

Change to App.js to:

```
import Detail  from  './components/pages/Detail';
```

Comment: In addition to this, it looks like the component is actually named `list` rather than `List` in the default export.

Comment: The file names are also mixed up. But the main error as I see is either he should `import Detail ...``` instead of `import { Detail }...` or `export { Detail }` instead of `export default Detail`

Comment: Oh yeah I totally agree with you, that is the main problem.  I was just pointing out the additional problem (which may actually be limited to the post and is correct in the code).